# Opaque events intersection in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I can not understand, does google-calendar controls `transparency=opaque` on events? Why I can create opaque events on the same time? Is `transparency` property for third-party software, which may control and prevent intersection for such events?

Answer (score 1):

[**Transparency**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations)

> - "**opaque**" - The event blocks time on the calendar. This is the default value.
> - "**transparent**" - The event does not block time on the calendar.

In terms that it blocks time, transparency sets the attendees status to busy(opaque) or available(transparent). In the [Google Calendar Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/FGvvgTrhgEs), this forum discuss how to set the default status in the event as available/busy.

Comment: so, transparency is not for block time for new events? it is just for checking attendees status of FreeBusy query?

Comment: Yup, I also got curious on these because I tried and opaque transparency doesn't block overlapping events. Nice question :)

Comment: I try realize strict "no overlap for events" constraint, but can not understand how to do it.

Comment: Strict no overlap is only a lab (called auto-declining events) and is not exposed via the API. One way to achieve this is to change the calendar settings (via the UI) to "Auto-accept invitations that do not conflict" (only works for secondary calendars)